# How to deal with symbol containing minus sign in KDB?

Tags: symbols, kdb, q-lang, q-query

I got an annoying problem. We got stock symbol AGN-A in kdb+ database, but it seems almost impossible to query if this symbol is in a symbol list.  The following query does not work at all:

```
`$"A-o" in (`$"A-o";`R)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The reason that doesn't work is because your comparing before casting. You need to cast first and then compare:

```
q)(`$"A-o") in (`$"A-o";`R)
1b
```

Comment: In general, yes it can be awkward when your symbols have characters in them, but it should be ok if you deal with casted strings as you are doing in the example

Answer (score 2):

the initial sym cast `$ is being applied to the entire line, not just the "A-o" string.
q is left of right.
Brackets are your answer.

```
q)`$"A-o" in (`$"A-o";`R)
'type
  [0]  <>:0: `$"A-o" in (`$"A-o";`R)
                     ^
q)(`$"A-o") in (`$"A-o";`R)
1b
q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting parentheses around the left argument to in, as in:

```
(`$"A-o") in (`$"A-o";`R)
```

So, in a table, try:

```
t:([] sym:(`$"A-o";`R;`IBM); col2:1 2 3)
select from t where sym = `$"A-o"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover how you can fix your execution order using parenthesis. However it is possible to deal with symbols without characters like "-" by using the function [`.Q.id`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qid-purge) to purge bad characters, so that no conversion is necessary:

```
q).Q.id each (`$"A-o";`R)
`Ao`R
```

Simplifying the example above to:

```
q)`Ao in .Q.id each (`$"A-o";`R)
1b
```